# Equivalent of Devise (Ruby on Rails) in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, spring-mvc, devise

I worked on a couple of projects with Ruby on Rails and I used [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user authentication. Now, I started a project on Spring MVC and I would like to know what is the best solution in order to have a complete authentication flow similar to the one offered by Devise, or at least mention your what do you choose in these cases ? At the moment, I am currently reading more information about spring-security.

Comment: The standard in Spring MVC is the one explained [at their site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late and since there are 662 views with no answers, I guess any answer would be better than no answer

https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration

This project is the closest I have come near the devise gem. It covers all of the devise's feature